# Web app development - How to have inbound http requests hit multiple environments

Tags: http, debugging, testing, web, web-deployment

Like most web development, I have multiple environments:

- Local development
- Cloud staging
- Cloud production
- Cloud-based web debugging services like RequestBin or Runscope which allow you to inspect http requests

etc.

During development and testing I would like to have inbound http requests (whether they are from users, 3rd party webhooks, etc.) hit multiple endpoints at the same time.  Naturally I don't have control of the origination of those inbound requests.

How might I achieve for example, receiving a 3rd party webhook in both my production environment and development environment at the same time?

Update: Let me follow up with the broader question - Perhaps my feeling that this functionality is a requirement is misplaced.  The reason I am looking for this functionality is because it would vastly simplify configuration (for example, I would have to set up multiple instances of a 3rd party webhook in order to go to my multiple environments).  How are others handling this overall situation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this "natively" as this would be in direct violation of numerous protocols and standards. That said depending on how you want to handle the responses, you can create a router (software function, not networking device) that accepts the requests, issues new requests to each environment, aggregates those responses, and finally returns that to the client.

Comment: Totally agree I could build this, I was just looking for existing implementations.  Could you expand on "this would be in direct violation of numerous protocols and standards"?  Obviously the point about a single request having multiple responses is a good example of that, but I was interested in your thoughts regardless.

Comment: Are you looking to build something or do you want a open-source/commercially available ready-to-go solution?

Comment: I am open to all options. Ideally I would like to reuse something that already exists, whether it's an infrastructure product or some piece of open source code. Also I am wondering how other developers manage this scenario or if they even consider it a problem.

Comment: Building a rough POC will be pretty easy. But assuming this would become a mission critical implementation, your real challenges would be having a reliable framework to handle: queues, asynchronous requests, smart retries on failures (handling idempotent and non-idempotent requests).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, maybe what you are looking for, is a Topic system with publishers (producers) and subscribers (consumers). If it's what you need, maybe [AWS SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) can be a good option for that, it's free for 1M requests, and with it, you can configure your environments as subscribers then make the requests to a SNS topic, which will fanout them to the subscribers.

If you only want to log the requests, you can also use [PutsReq](http://putsreq.com/) as a proxy. Making the requests to PutsReq, and "re-passing" them to the real target.

```
// sample response builder
// https://github.com/phstc/putsreq#forwardto
request.forwardTo = 'http://production.com/api';
```

Comment: I don't think sns is appropriate here because I'm specifically looking for a proxy to forward or replay http requests. I did look at PutsReq but it appears limited to performing a single forward for a given request. I want to do multiple. I acknowledge that what I am looking to do isn't quite "natural" for lack of a better term.